# Htop in emacs' ansi-term won't resize

Tags: emacs, terminal, signals, ncurses, ansi-term

I am trying to run htop in ansi-term in a graphical (X session) emacs, and htop won't resize. Whatever size the window/frame is when I start htop is the size it continues to try rendering at forever.

Things I've tried:

1. Running ansi-term on htop directly and inside an ansi-term running zsh.
2. Manually sending a SIGWINCH w/ `kill -28 $pid` to the htop process. Also to the parent zsh process when there was one.
3. Telling emacs to send the signal with emacsclient eval'ing  `(signal-process nil 28)` and with `(signal-process (get-buffer-process (get-buffer "mybuffername")) 28)`. I know the signal gets through because sending signal 29 kills the process.

Interestingly plain ol' top *does* resize, *but only when the frame containing its buffer has X input focus*. Htop still doesn't resize regardless of focus though. Also interestingly emacs itself running in console mode in ansi-term *does* resize, *but only when given input*. So you have to press up or down or write a character first or something.

Ideally all 3 would always resize immediately when the window does. Emacs has a hook for detecting this, I just need to know what to tell the hook to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `proced`?

Comment: This is my first time hearing of it and it looks awesome.

Comment: It really is: `isearch`, `occur` or any other Emacs feature is readily available in `proced`.

Comment: Unfortunately proced updates really slowly, even when I set its update interval to 1 second. The CPU usage still seems to change extremely slowly, to the point where I'm not confident its accurate at all. I can do actions in an app that cause my CPU to vary wildly in top and proced will show a constant 15%.